# Match any/all of multiple words in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write this regEx (javascript) to match `word1` and `word2` (when it exists):

`This is a test. Here is word1 and here is word2, which may or may not exist.`

I tried these:

---

`(word1).*(word2)?`

This will match only `word1` regardless if `word2` exists or not.

---

`(word1).*(word2)`

This will match both but *only* if both exists.

---

I need a regex to match word1 and word2 - which may or may not exist.

Comment: Why don't you simply test their existence individually?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
var str = "This is a test. Here is word1 and here is word2, which may or may not exist.";
var matches = str.match( /word1|word2/g );
//-> ["word1", "word2"]
```

[`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) will run a regex against the string and find all matching hits. In this case we use [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to allow the regex to match either `word1` or `word2`.

You need to apply the global flag to the regex so that `match()` will find all results.

If you care about matching only on word boundaries, use `/\b(?:word1|word2)\b/g`.

Comment: Are you sure this will not match `(word)(1|w)(ord2)`. Edit: No you are right.

Comment: @Krycke - it's not clear if that's important or not. I've addressed it in an edit.

Comment: That's it! So trivial and I missed it. I got confused that `|` in regex would mean the same as `||` (or) operator in javascript.